# angular http get using c#.Net

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Angular 2.4 and using Visual Studio 2017. I have created a project using .NET Core 1.1. I am trying to use some of the code from the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial. I have created a controller in Visual Studio .Net using the Web API and it is successfully returning a JSON file of customer data.

Similar to the tutorial, I am creating a customer.service.ts and customers.component.ts.

I am getting a 404 File Not Found error on the calls to getCustomers(). I am having trouble figuring out why it isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code snippet for the customer.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Customer } from './customer';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    private customerUrl = 'api/customer';  // URL to web api
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private customers: Customer[];

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getCustomers(): Promise<Customer[]> {
        return this.http.get('api/customer')
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Customer[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Here is the code snippet for customers.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Customer } from './customer';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'customers',
    templateUrl: './customers.component.html',

    // an array of style file names (with paths).
    styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css'],
})

export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Northwind Customers';
    public customers: Customer[];
    selectedCustomer: Customer;
    http: Http;

    constructor(private router: Router, private customerService: CustomerService) { }

    onSelect(customer: Customer): void {
        this.selectedCustomer = customer;
    }

    getCustomers(): void {
        //this.customers = this.customerService.getCustomers();
        this.customerService.getCustomers().then(customers => this.customers = customers);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

Here is the customers.component.html:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<h2>Customers</h2>

<div>
    <label>Company name:</label> <input #companyName />
    <button (click)="add(companyName.value); companyName.value=''">Add</button>
</div>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let customer of customers" 
        [class.selected]="customer === selectedCustomer">
        <span class="badge">{{customer.customerID}}</span> 
        <span>{{customer.companyName}}</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the customer.ts:

```
export class Customer {
    customerID: string;
    companyName: string;
    contactName: string;
    contactTitle: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
    region: string;
    postalCode: string;
    country: string;
    phone: string;
    fax: string;
}
```

My ASP.NET controller seems to be working. It returns a JSON file with the data when I navigate to api/customer in the browser. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NorthwindAngular.DAL;
using NorthwindAngular.Models;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace NorthwindAngular.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly NorthwindContext _context;

        public CustomerController(NorthwindContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/values
        //[HttpGet("[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
        {
            return _context.Customers.ToList();
        }

        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Customer Get(string id)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                return null;
            else
                return _context.Customers.Find(id);
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your angular is working, what function is the route on 'api/customer' pointing to?

Comment: If you can post the code in your controller which you are trying to call, that would be helpful as well. otherwise it seems like you are just missing the `localhost:[port]` in the `url` you are using in your `get`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. The solution was to redo the http.get calls using Observable rather than Promise.

See [Fetch data with http.get()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data) in the Angular documentation for more detail.

### customer.service.ts

The key here was that ASP.NET returns the JSON without a data element, so the `extractData` function needs to use `body` instead of `body.data` which is shown in the [Tour of Heroes Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import { Customer } from './customer';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    private customerUrl = 'api/customers';  // URL to web api
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private customers: Customer[];

    // the Angular Http client service is injected into the constructor
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.customerUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;

        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }

        console.error(errMsg);

        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

### customer.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Customer } from './customer';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'customers',
    templateUrl: './customers.component.html',

    // an array of style file names (with paths).
    styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css'],
})

export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Northwind Customers';
    customers: Customer[];
    selectedCustomer: Customer;
    errorMessage: string;
    http: Http;

    // Inject a Router nad CustomerService needed by this component
    constructor(private router: Router, private customerService: CustomerService) { }

    onSelect(customer: Customer): void {
        this.selectedCustomer = customer;
    }

    gotoDetail(): void {
        // Note that you're passing a two-element link parameters array 
        // — a path and the route parameter
        //this.router.navigate(['/customer-detail', this.selectedCustomer.customerID]);
    }

    getCustomers(): void {
        //this.customers = this.customerService.getCustomers();
        this.customerService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe(
            customers => this.customers = customers,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getCustomers();
    }
}
```

### customer.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<h2>Customers</h2>

<div>
    <label>Company name:</label> <input #companyName />
    <button (click)="add(companyName.value); companyName.value=''">Add</button>
</div>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let customer of customers" 
        [class.selected]="customer === selectedCustomer"
        (click)="onSelect(customer)">
        <span class="badge">{{customer.customerID}}</span> 
        <span>{{customer.companyName}}</span>
        <button class="delete"
            (click)="delete(customer); $event.stopPropagation()">x</button>

    </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="selectedCustomer">
    <h2>
        <!-- 
            Pipes are a good way to format strings, currency amounts, 
            dates and other display data. 
        -->
        {{selectedCustomer.companyName | uppercase}} is my hero
    </h2>
    <button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>
</div>

<div class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">
    {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not giving the full url of the web api, append the url  with the localhost address like

```
 http.get('http://localhost:[port number where your api is running]/api/customer')
```

Comment: No that doesn't work and angular supports relative urls.